# Angular dropdown changing other dropdowns

Tags: angular, ngfor, ng-template, ng-container

I have a situation when i select the drop down it changes the value in other dropdowns on the page as well.

I tried to figure out what was causing the issue and i notice that it goes away if i remove the trackBy in ngFor.

Unfortunately, i need the trackBy to improve performance.

Any clue why this is happening ? Here is a stackblitz demonstrating the problem :

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-27snjx

Comment: The problem here is that you are using the same `dataset` and the same `value` for all of your dropdowns. That is why change in one affects other.

Comment: smithnblack : I tried your technique and the issue still persists. thats a valid scenario though. We would have only one dataset of reference data on one page and reuse it. It also doesnt explain why removing trackBy makes it work.